# String serial communication

Tags: java, android, serial-port, arduino

I'm just learning Java for about a couple weeks now. My end goal is to have my Arduino measure some sensors and send the results to my android via USB cable. However I'm just trying to get my Arduino to communicate with the Java console on my computer first, and then I figure it's pretty much copy and paste from there.

I can get my Arduino and Java console to communicate with each other as long as it's a simple byte.  Anything passed that is giving me a result of the quadratic equation exploding.

In my Arduino serial Monitor I get this:

> Engine Temp:100
>
> Air Temp:95
>
> Engine Speed:10000 RPM
>
> Wheel Speed:30 MPH

and in my Java console I get this:

> Normal println
>   [B@6f5f6479
>
> String
>   €˜3Àf`Ìó€˜€
>
> UTF
>   ??3?f`??

Here is my reader code:

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1000];
                try {
                    int availableBytes = input.available();
                    if (availableBytes > 0) {
                        // Read the serial port
                        input.read(readBuffer, 0, availableBytes);

                        // Print it out
                        System.out.println("Normal println");
                        System.out.println(readBuffer);
                        System.out.println("\nString");
                        System.out.println(new String(readBuffer, 0, availableBytes));
                        System.out.println("\nUTF");
                        System.out.println(new String(readBuffer,"UTF-8"));
                        System.out.println("\nDone");
                    }}



                 catch (IOException e) {

            }

    }
```

input is my InputStream.

Comment: Have you looked at the Arduino output in serial monitor?  Do we know that the problem is in the Java code?  How is `input` declared?

Comment: Yes, I posted that right under where I said "In my Arduino serial Monitor I get this:" I'm almost positive the problem is in the java code. input is declared as InputStream from package java.io.InputStream

Comment: Can you add the code showing how `input` is constructed and opened?  It would be useful to see how it associated with your serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Arduino and the serial port on the android are at the same speed.  The provided code does NOT show how the serial ports are defined and opened/started so its impossible to know if this is the problem.

The characters displayed at the android appear like the typical garbage seen when the two end-points of a serial line are not similarly configured.

It looks like the Arduino is correctly sensing the engine's dynamics?